# how to call this script in an .aspx file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm beginner to jquery, how to call this script in an .aspx page?

```
 var text = '';

    $('p').bind('keypress', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text('');
    $(this).empty();

    text += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    var text2 = text.substr(0, text.length - 1);
    var lastChar = text.substr(text.length - 1);

    $(this).text(text2);

    $(this).append('<span class="char">' + lastChar + '</span>');
    $(this).append('<span class="cursor"></span>');

    });
```

appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: nobody, but I need it :)

Comment: @CharlesTian. Webforms still has some benefits over MVC. Also, it's not like everybody can just rewrite all their webforms apps in mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, wrap your code into a function. Use one of the following to write a call to the function.

[RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx)
[RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)